# JQuery image selection

Tags: jquery, css

This should be pretty self explanatory, any help much appreciated!

Jquery Code

```
    $("#larrow img").hide();
    $("#rarrow img").hide();

    $("#rarrow").hover(arrowIn,arrowOut);
    $("#larrow").hover(arrowIn,arrowOut);

    function arrowIn()
    {
    $(this+" img").show()
    }
    function arrowOut()
    {
    $(this+" img").hide()
    }
```

I also tried this with the img as the background

```
    $("#larrow").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#rarrow").css('visibility','hidden');

    $("#rarrow").hover(arrowIn,arrowOut);
    $("#larrow").hover(arrowIn,arrowOut);

    function arrowIn()
    {
    $(this).css('visibility','visible')
    }
    function arrowOut()
    {
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden')
    }
```

obviously to no avail, thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `this` with `img` selector. Anyway, this code may be shorter:

```
function arrow() {
    $("img", this).toggle();
}

$("#larrow img, #rarrow img").hide();
$("#rarrow, #larrow").hover(arrow);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4fHL3/

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the Html you can try this:

```
function arrowIn()
{
    $(this).show();
}
function arrowOut()
{
    $(this).hide();
}
```

OR

```
function arrowIn()
{
    $('img', this).show();
}
function arrowOut()
{
    $('img', this).hide();
}
```